# Return True if each row in table results in an even sum, False otherwise in Python

Tags: python, sum

My code so far:

```
def evenrow(table):
    for i in table:
        if sum(i) % 2 == 1:
            return False
    return True
```

But when ran nothing is returned.
An example of callling it:

```
>>> evenrow([[1,3],[2,4],[0,6]])
    #but nothing is returned here, but should return True. Why?
```

EDIT: I WAS AN IDIOT AND FORGOT A PARENTHESIS IN MY CALL!

Comment: How are you executing it? Are you calling your function somewhere else in your code, or are you calling it from an interactive shell?

Comment: your function works in the interpreter.  I'm guessing you have it saved as a script, it which case you need to pass the result to print or some other io function to get it to display.

Comment: I'm running it in the python 3.4 script.

Answer (score 0):

It works fine for me:

```
def evenrow(table):
    for i in table:
        if sum(i) % 2 == 1:
            return False
    return True

print evenrow([[1,3], [2,4], [0,6]])
print evenrow([[1,3,2], [3,4,7], [0,5,2]])
```

The output is

```
Testing started at 4:12 PM ...
True
False

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Does anything in this sequence help you find what you're missing?

Comment: With your print of evenrow that what I type in to the console when I run the script. Then when ran it should return true or false.

Answer (score 0):

If you just run it in the python shell, you will get your desired output. However, if you run a python script, then you will need to print the value which is being returned from the function.

So, in your python script, change: `evenrow([[1,3], [2,4], [0,6]])` to the following:

```
print(evenrow([[1,3], [2,4], [0,6]]))
```